# how to make inside div's as wide as the parent (column) and responsive?

Tags: css

On [this page](http://www.amordetango.nl/txp/agenda/) (responsive site in progress) the background image of the containing div (article) is as wide as the longest sentence (p). So they don't are as wide as the column (#main = 30em). What can I do with CSS to make all div's as wide as the column and still have their responsiveness intact?

```
#agenda #main article {
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
    background: #fff url() repeat;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0;
}

#agenda #main article h3 {
    color: #666;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: .4em;
    padding-top: .4em;
}

#agenda #main article h4 {
    color: #666;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: .4em;
    padding-top: .4em;
}

#agenda #main article p {
    color: #666;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `float: left` from the `#main article` in your css (line 402) or override it with `float: none`.

Comment: It works ... :) ... but can you explain why this works? I'm not a noob but I don't know everything.

Comment: Sure. A block level element takes up 100% of the width of it's parent by default (a div, for example). If you float an element left or right and don't specify a width, it's will only be as wide as it's children. Floats should be used for positioning in a certain way, a good example being an image right aligned in some text. Good article here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thanks @thebiffboff ... I'm a trial and error guy you know, but sometimes exact know-how is necessary ... :)

Comment: Oh, me too, nothing wrong with knowledge learned through trial and error!

Answer (score 0):

Can't really test the responsiveness on mobile devices at the moment, but it seems that you simply need to add a width:100% to your article elements:

```
#agenda #main article {
background: url("") repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
margin-bottom: 1em;
width: 100%;
```

}

Tried it in firebug and it looks fine even when I'm zooming in or out.

Comment: Only problem with this is that the article elements have padding so this will get added on in the box model, making them wider than their container. There is no need for them to be floated, and removing the float: left will make them behave like a regular block-level element which is what is required.

Comment: True, hadn't noticed the padding issue. Removing the float:left is indeed what you want.